# Creating draggable div on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am currently using the framework `knockout.js` in combination with jquery ui(to make the div draggables). I have been able to hard code the number of draggable divs and with text appended = `self.items(['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six']);` . I would like to make it more dynamic. How would I be able to create new divs on a button click event that will also append text a text area to the new div? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/P9C7E/21/)

Knockout.js

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).draggable();
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.droppable={
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).droppable();
    }
};

var vm=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.items=ko.observableArray();
    self.init=function(){
        self.items(['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six']);
    }
    self.remove=function(item){
        console.log(item);
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

HTML

```
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Generate New Div</button>
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
    <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[X]</span><br><br>
        <center><span  data-bind="text:$data"></span></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an observable bound to the textarea

```
self.textContent = ko.observable('');

<textarea data-bind="value: textContent"></textarea>
```

The create an add function, bind it to the button and push a new value to the observable array

```
self.addNew = function() {
  self.items.push( self.textContent() );
  self.textContent('');
}

<button data-bind="click: addNew">Generate New Div</button>
```